# Numpy array. Covert list within array into dimension

Tags: python, numpy, arcpy

I am using [TableToNumpyArray](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/tabletonumpyarray.htm) from arcpy.  The table 'x' I am importing has 99 rows and 6 columns.

```
x
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8frB.png)

```
print(x)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjZSv.png)

```
np.shape(x)
(99,)
```

I want to convert it into (99,6) with no lists.

Based on comments and previous answers I tried:

```
y = np.stack(x)
np.shape(y)
(99,)
```

Comment: Is `np.stack(x)` working?

Comment: No I tried that based on previous answers but it does not work.

Comment: Are you sure the columns are still there? 
Can you please edit the post and add at least a part of how printing the array looks?

Comment: @ChocolateBear I have added screenshots. I cannot figure out if inline images are possible.

Comment: Notice the array you got there *is* a one dimensional numpy array!
This is an array containing tuple objects (not even a tuple as is).

Comment: @thomas can you please print/share the type of the elements of the array? e.g.  print(type(x[0]))

Comment: @ChocolateBear
type(x[0]) = numpy.void / type(x[0][0]) = numpy.float64 / type(x) = numpy.ndarray

Comment: what is `x.dtype`?  You may have a structured array.  Or show the end of that `Out[168]` display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the docs for

```
TableToNumPyArray
ArcGIS Pro 2.8 | Other versions
Summary
Converts a table to NumPy structured array.
```

Your `x` `Out[168]` display is not complete; it is missing the final `dtype` line.  If you think the array should be (99,6), then that `dtype` must have 6 `fields`.

No amount of `stack`, `concatenate` or `reshape` is going to convert the `fields` to `columns`.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html

Here's a sample structured dtype and array:

```
In [23]: dt = np.dtype('f,f,f')
In [24]: dt
Out[24]: dtype([('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
In [25]: arr = np.ones(4, dtype=dt)
In [26]: arr
Out[26]: 
array([(1., 1., 1.), (1., 1., 1.), (1., 1., 1.), (1., 1., 1.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
```

Note how the display looks like a list of tuples.  And note the dtype.

Since all fields are floats. one nice way to create a 2d numeric array is:

```
In [27]: arr.tolist()
Out[27]: [(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)]
In [28]: np.array(arr.tolist())
Out[28]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

`tolist()` is relatively fast.

Another way is to use a `recfunctions` utility:

```
In [29]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf
In [30]: rf.structured_to_unstructured(arr)
Out[30]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

With a common field dtype, `view` can also be used, but it requires reshaping:

```
In [32]: arr.view(np.float32)
Out[32]: array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.], dtype=float32)
In [33]: arr.view(np.float32).reshape(4,3)
Out[33]: 
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

A nasty issue, but I found multiple solutions.
First, notice that the type of elements in your array is "object" (edit: You just posted your type, it **is** different but I do think the solution should work for you as well. The np.stack solution you were given should work as well but you forgot to reshape it), therefore you have a 1D array of objects, and when you ask for its shape - you get (99,)

So let's create an example array of the same type as yours:

```
l=[(1,2),(3,4)]
a = np.empty(len(l), dtype=tuple)
a[:] = l

print(f"a's shape: {a.shape}")
```

It's output is : `a's shape: (2,)`

The classic solution to this is to create a list from it and the rebuild the numpy array normally like so:

```
print(np.array(list(a)).shape)
```

which outputs `(2, 2)`

But you asked to do so without lists. Another approach would be using "concatenate" like so:

```
a = np.concatenate(a).reshape(len(a),*np.shape(a[0]))
```

Which also results in what you want.
What we do here is concatenate the tuples together, one after the other - as one big array, and then reshape it to the desired length.

EDIT: same goes for the stack solution you were offered, you forgot to reshape afterwards

```
a= np.stack(a).reshape(len(a),*np.shape(a[0]))
```

Comment: `type void` indicates a compound dtype, not object dtype.  `dtype=tuple` just makes object dtype.

Comment: `concatenate` (and `vstack` and `stack`) treats the argument as an iterable, a list of arrays.   Converting an array to "pure" lists is really not so bad (time wise), `arr.tolist()`